# BlackBerry AutoComplete field with white background?

Tags: user-interface, blackberry, background

I have a problem with changing the background of `AutoCompleteField`. No matter what I try, the background is gray all the time (isn't it strange it is gray by default in the first place...).

Anyone knows how to make the background white (like it is for instance in BlackBerry email client)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've seen this question asked before on the BB dev forums with no responses, so I'm curious as well.  Historically the look and feel of the standard UI controls have been notoriously difficult (or impossible) to customize, so it may just not be possible.

Comment: Hm, I see your point. However there is `AutoCompleteField` with white background in BB email client (recipient fields). So, either it is possible somehow or they created another type of field for this special case.

Answer (score 0):

The BB way is to extend existing Fields whenever you want to change their style (for example color), so here is my solution:

[image: screenshot]

MyAuto.java:

```
package mypackage;

import net.rim.device.api.ui.*;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.*;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.*;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.decor.*;
import net.rim.device.api.system.*;
import net.rim.device.api.collection.util.*;

public class MyAuto extends UiApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyAuto myAuto = new MyAuto();
        myAuto.enterEventDispatcher();
    }

    public MyAuto () {
        pushScreen(new MyScreen());
    }    
}

class MyScreen extends MainScreen {
    public MyScreen() {
        BasicFilteredList filterList = new BasicFilteredList();
        String[] days = {"Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday",
                        "Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"};
        filterList.addDataSet(1,days,"days",BasicFilteredList.COMPARISON_IGNORE_CASE);
        Background myBG = BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        Border myBorder = BorderFactory.createBitmapBorder( 
            new XYEdges( 20, 16, 27, 23 ), 
            Bitmap.getBitmapResource( "bubble_left.png" ) );
        AutoCompleteField autoCompleteField = new AutoCompleteField(filterList);
        autoCompleteField.setBorder(myBorder);
        autoCompleteField.getEditField().setBackground(myBG);
        add(autoCompleteField);
    }
}
```

The [bubble_left.png](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800505/800608/How_to_-_Implement_advanced_buttons,_fields,_and_managers.html?nodeid=2406256&vernum=0) is not really needed, I've added it just for fun:

[image]

BTW in my simulator (BB 9800) the background is white by default.